# Can you help me to identify the rounding of this application?

Tags: algorithm, function, math, rounding, approximation

I've a application that output chunk of buffers that represent 1/96 of beat (lets call them pulses), using a Sample Rate of 44100.

At constant 120 BPM, I have 2 beat per second, so 22050 samples per beat, thus 229,6875 samples per pulse. These are the first values I got from the application:

```
0
230
459
689
919
1148
1378
1608
1838
2067
2297
2527
2756
2986
3216
3445
3675
3905
4134
4364
4594
4823
5053
5283
5512
5742
5972
6202
6431
```

Notice two things:

1. it rounds the values using **[Round half to Even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)**;
2. the distance between buffers can be 229 or 230 due to the rounding.

At constant 190 BPM instead, I have 145,0657895 samples per pulse. First values I got:

```
0
145
290
435
580
725
870
1015
1161
1306
1451
1596
1741
1886
2031
2176
2321
2466
2611
2756
2901
3046
3191
3337
3482
3627
3772
3917
4062
```

As before, Round half to Even, and the distance now can be 145 or 146.

Well, nothing hard till here. Now! If I start the application at 120 BPM and after 25 pulse I switch to 190 BPM, I got a weird distance after the switch:

```
0
230     // distance 230
459     // distance 229
689     // distance 230
919     // distance 230
1148    // distance 229
1378    // distance 230
1608    // distance 230
1838    // distance 230
2067    // distance 229
2297    // distance 230
2527    // distance 230
2756    // distance 229
2986    // distance 230
3216    // distance 230
3445    // distance 229
3675    // distance 230
3905    // distance 230
4134    // distance 229
4364    // distance 230
4594    // distance 230
4823    // distance 229
5053    // distance 230
5283    // distance 230
5512    // distance 229
5742    // distance 230 - here I switch
5887    // distance 145
6032    // distance 145
6177    // distance 145
6322    // distance 145
6468    // distance 146
```

Why that last 146 values (6468)?

In your opinion, due to "what" the distance between prev buffer is 146 and not 145? Tried to round next/prev at each iterations, but it seems correct to get 145 as value there. Instead its 146.

It's confusing all my counters. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 229.6875 * 25 = 5742.1875
 145.0657895 * 5 = 725.3289475
 5742.1875 + 725.3289475 = 6467.5164475 rounding to 6468
```

Note that underlying calculations are made in exact (merely float) numbers